# Move multiple pictureboxes at once of the same variable name C#

Tags: c#, animation

```
    private void ingame_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            bullet = new PictureBox();
            bullet.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.bullet;
            bullet.Size = new Size(8, 30);
            bullet.Location = new Point(246, 364);
            bullet.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            bullet.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            this.Controls.Add(bullet);

            this.SuspendLayout();
            bullet.Location = new Point(bullet.Location.X, bullet.Location.Y - 10);
            this.ResumeLayout();
            timer1.Interval = 10;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bullet.Location = new Point(bullet.Location.X, bullet.Location.Y-1);
    }
```

Each time the spacebar is clicked a new bullet is created, but if you have a bullet already on the screen it freezes and the new one moves. Is there a way to make them both/more move?

Comment: Where is your `bullet` variable actually declared?  Did you mean to keep a collection of bullets instead of just one?  Like a `List<PictureBox>` ?

Comment: If you want to keep track of multiple bullets then you need a collection.  Consider a `List<PictureBox>`.  With some luck that is going to evolve into a `List<GameObject>`.

Comment: Thanks, it is declared just outside the procedures as "public PictureBox bullet;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a `PictureBox`.  What you want is a `List<PictureBox>`.  For example:

```
public List<PictureBox> bullets = new List<PictureBox>();
```

(I would recommend a private member, or even a property, but just to keep minimal changes from your current code this should be fine.)

First, remove your timer logic from the KeyDown event and put it somewhere that only executes once, such as FormLoad.  You only need one timer ticking.

Then in your KeyDown event, add new "bullets" to your list.  Something like this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
{
    // declare a local variable
    var bullet = new PictureBox();

    // set the rest of the properties and add the control to the form like you normally do

    // but also add it to the new class-level list:
    bullets.Add(bullet);
}
```

Then in your timer tick event, simply loop through the list:

```
foreach (var bullet in bullets)
    bullet.Location = new Point(bullet.Location.X, bullet.Location.Y-1);
```